# MySQL Docker Container storing password after first run

Tags: mysql, docker

All my experience with Docker so far has led me to believe that containers are stateless.

If so, why is my container storing the password that I change it to after the first run if I spun it up without specifying a volume or bind mount? I am especially puzzled since none of the other edits I make to the dbms persist (like creating tables).

**Additional Details:**
Versions:
1. Docker - 18.09.0 build 4d60db4
2. Image - mysql/mysql-server:latest

Commands:
 1. `$ docker run --name=sql -d mysql/mysql-server:latest`
 2. `$ docker logs sql 2>&1 | grep GENERATED` to grab the generated password for first login
 3. `$ docker exec -it sql mysql -uroot -p`
 4. `mysql> Enter Password: <generated password>`
 5. `mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'stkoverflw';`
 6. `mysql> exit`
 7. `$ docker stop sql`
 8. `$ docker start sql`
 9. `$ docker exec -it sql mysql -uroot -p`
 10. `mysql> Enter Password: <stkoverflw>`

How does the password configuration persist across restarts of the container?

Comment: can you show an example including version? Afaik its stateless too.

Comment: I've edited the post to include additional details.

Comment: Show your actual commands so that we can reproduce the problem. Steps #3, #4 and #5 do not show "commands" contrary to the caption before the list.

Comment: Pardon me, I've fixed that

Comment: But you are defining a volume to `/var/lib/mysql/ ` on step 1. The mysql password is stored there!

Comment: I've actually done this even on containers without volumes mounted -- with the same result. Let me change the commands to ensure this doesn't interfere with my question.

Comment: if you `docker kill sql` and re-run it that's when you'll loose the data.

Comment: Sure, but where is that data stored and why does it persist? (As opposed to say, SQL writes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are not stateless. Containers are easy to create and destroy, so they can be used to run a service which is stateless, but each container is itself stateful.

When the container is running, there is a volume containing its root filesystem. You don't have to tell Docker to create it. Docker has to create it because otherwise where do the container's files go?

When you say `docker stop`, the container stops running but it is not destroyed. When you say `docker start`, the same container resumes with the same root volume. That's where the changed password persists. The process running in the container was stopped and a new process was started (so state held in memory would be lost), but the filesystem is still there.

To get rid of a container (including the changed password), say `docker rm`. Then you can say `docker run` to start from scratch.